# Remove a C++ observer from NSNotification?

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

In C++, it is not hard to add an Observer for a notification. But the problem is that how could I remove an Observer.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"SENTENCE_FOUND" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
```

So normally we use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SENTENCE_FOUND" object:nil];
```

to remove an observer.

But since C++ doesn't have `self` and when I use `this`, I got the following error

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id _Nonnull' with an rvalue of type 'DialogSystem *'
```

So how could I remove a C++ class observer? Or it is impossible?

Comment: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] self name:@"SENTENCE_FOUND" object:nil];` isn't proper Objective-C syntax, post real code please.

Comment: @Willeke Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1411723-addobserverforname?language=occ) of `-[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]`:

> **Return Value**
>
> An opaque object to act as the observer.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If a given notification triggers more than one observer block, the blocks may all be executed concurrently with respect to one another (but on their given queue or on the current thread).
>
> The following example shows how you can register to receive locale change notifications.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
self.localeChangeObserver = [center addObserverForName:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil
    queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) { 
        NSLog(@"The user's locale changed to: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
    }];
```

> To unregister observations, you pass the object returned by this method to removeObserver:. You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center removeObserver:self.localeChangeObserver];
```

**Edit:** Copied from the same page:

> Another common pattern is to create a one-time notification by removing the observer from within the observation block, as in the following example.

```
NSNotificationCenter * __weak center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
id __block token = [center addObserverForName:@"OneTimeNotification"
                                       object:nil
                                        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                       NSLog(@"Received the notification!");
                                       [center removeObserver:token];
                                   }];
```

Comment: But how could I unregister the observer inside the Block? I cannot access the return value in the block for the return value.

Comment: How do you unregister if you don't receive the notification?

Comment: My logic is that after receiving the notification, I will do some stuff, and then unregister itself. The code in the block will run after receiving the notification, right?

Comment: Does the code in the block use any data from outside the block?

Comment: There is no "C++ observer inside the block" as far as Cocoa/ObjC are concerned. That method creates an Objective-C object that is the actual observer (the one it returns) and that calls the block. You have to remove *that* object as documented. NSNotificationCenter doesn't care about what the code inside the block does.